# Behaviour of threads with combination of synchronized methods in a class

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

### Case 1

I have 2 synchronized methods as shown below:

```
class A {
    public void synchronized methodA() {}
    public void synchronized methodB() {}
}
```

**A:** I have threads T1 and T2. Can the threads simultaneously execute`methodA` and `methodB` (respectively) belonging to the *same* instance of class A?

- My analysis: The answer is **no** because only one method will be executed by thread T1 and thread T2 will be blocked until T1 finishes execution.

**B:** I have threads T1 and T2. Can the threads simultaneously execute `methodA` and `methodB` (respectively) belonging to *different* instances of class A?

- My analysis: The answer is **yes** because T1 and T2 can execute `methodA` and `methodB` belonging to different instances of class A and they will not be blocked.

Is my understanding correct as per my analysis for case 1?

### Update: Case 2

I have 2 synchronized methods, one is non static and the other is static.

```
class A {        
    public void synchronized methodA() {}    
    public void static synchronized methodB() {}    
}
```

**A:** I have threads T1 and T2.  Can the threads simultaneously execute `methodA` and  `methodB` (respectively) belonging to the *same* instance of class A?

- My analysis: The answer is **no** because only one method will be executed by T1 and T2 will be blocked until T1 finishes execution.

**B:** I have threads T1 and T2. Can the threads simultaneously execute `methodA` and `methodB` (respectively) belonging to *different* instances of class A?

- My analysis: The answer is **yes** because T1 and T2 can execute `methodA` and `methodB` belonging to different instances and they will not be blocked.

Is my understanding correct as per my analysis for case 2?

Comment: If you're going to add more questions, the please change the title to fit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Case A: No

Case B: Yes

Your analysis is correct.  A synchronized keyword on an instance method is functionally equivalent to this:

```
public void someMethod() {
   synchronized(this) {
      //code
   }
}
```

Since `this` is different in the two contexts, they are not mutually exclusive.  Note that even the same method could be called at the same time for two different instances.

### Edit

For case 2, you are incorrect on 2A; it doesn't even make sense.  A static synchronized method does not "belong" to an instance of the class; if it did it wouldn't be static!  It doesn't synchronize on *any* instance of the class (it has no reference to an instance to synchronize on!) so it instead synchronizes on the class object of `A`.  A static synchronized method in class `A` is equivalent to this:

```
public static void methodB() {
   synchronized (A.class) {
      //code
   }
}
```

Your instance method will synchronize on the instance as I've shown above, so the two threads can run in parallel.

In case B then, obviously they also can run in parallel but you're still missing the fundamental concept that a static method is not associated with *any* instance.

Comment: Thanks @Peter...@Peter i wanted to just ask one question out of curiosity,I had attended one such intw,where in the intervwer came after completing the intw that there was no requirement for java after conducting the intw what do you think i should do i such a case.

Comment: @Deepak: My name's Mark, not Peter.  But I can't give you career advice without context, and here's certainly not the place to ask (particularly on an unrelated question).  Maybe try out http://programmers.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Sorry...Kindly excuse me.@Mark

Comment: @Mark,what abt CASE2A and CASE2B,can you give me their respective answers.

Comment: @Mark,what abt CASE2A and CASE2B,can you give me their respective answers,i need to close this question quickly,can anyone answer the second CASE2A and CASE2B ???

Comment: Thanks Peter i have got the answer.hence CASE 2A and CASE 2B : Both are yes. if my understanding is correct now.

Comment: @Deepak: my name's still not Peter.  And yes it looks like you've got it now.

Comment: @Mark,sorry for the name confusion,there are so many Marks,Peters,Franklinns that i forget to use the right name,apologise for the same.Hence CASE2A and CASE2B are both Yes.Accepting your answer as the final solution.

Answer (score 0):

**Case 1:** You are correct.

Every Java object has (among other things) an associated mutual exclusion lock (mutex). When `synchronized` is applied to a non-static method, it is the instance's mutex that is locked. Thus `synchronized` methods work on a per-object basis.

Static `synchronized` methods use the lock of the Class object, so operate on a per-class basis (modulo ClassLoader) and independently of non-static methods. You can also use `synchronized()` in method bodies to use the lock of any object you wish.

**Case 2:** You are not correct, as methodA() and methodB() use different mutexes, as described above.

Comment: @Orange:CASE 2 : can you explain with an example Plz

Comment: @Deepak - Not really. You already gave the example, but what you said will happen won't.

Comment: @Orange so whats the answer for CASE 2A and CASE 2B

Comment: @Deepak - You only have 3 possibilities left, plus I have just described how everything works. Can you not reach the answer yourself?

Comment: CASE 2A and CASE2B: BOTH NO,since they are using different mutexes

Comment: @Deepak - Perhaps you should lookup the meaning of "mutual exclusion" and "independently".

Comment: @orange,could you please explain for CASE 2A and CASE 2B,is my Answer correct,if not whats the answer ?

Comment: @Deepak - I have explained. Neither of the answers you have suggested are correct.

Comment: @Orange,please tell me the correct answer,im not sure the answer for CASE 2A and CASE 2b should be BOTH YES,since you mentioned abt independently.so each of them is exceuting in its own context